# how to Find difference between todays date and second date

Tags: apex

I have the following query but it gives me error at the WHERE CLAUSE. 
Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token '.'. at line

```
SELECT Id,Date__c,On_Call_Type_c__c,UserRegion__c,RegionInformation__r.Time_Slot__c,
       Registered_User_Email__c,Registered_User_Name__c,Notification_Email_Sent__c 
   FROM SRE_Registtartion__c WHERE Date__c.daysBetween(today()) = 4 AND
        Notification_Email_Sent__c = false
```

Comment: LHS of a where condition must be a field name; you are using an expression `Date__c.daysBetween(today())`

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to precompute Date values in Apex that you can bind into your expression as comparands. You cannot compute an Apex expression on each row and filter based upon it.

You'd want to do something like

```
Date fourDaysAgo = Date.today().addDays(-4);

List<SRE_Registtartion__c> registrations = [
    SELECT Id,Date__c,On_Call_Type_c__c,UserRegion__c,RegionInformation__r.Time_Slot__c,
   Registered_User_Email__c,Registered_User_Name__c,Notification_Email_Sent__c 
    FROM SRE_Registtartion__c 
    WHERE Date__c = :fourDaysAgo AND
    Notification_Email_Sent__c = false
];
```

A similar tactic would apply if you wanted to use a date range, a greater-than, or a date in the future; you just have to ensure that your dynamic value is the comparand, and may choose to precompute it to simplify (although static SOQL does allow expressions in bindings).